# Thread dump not getting generated on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jvm, thread-dump

I used to generate thread dumps by running kill -quit and I would get them in a log file where my server logs were there. When the file grew too large I removed it using rm and created a new file of the same name.
Now when I use kill -quit to take the thread dumps, nothing gets copied in the log file - its empty.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

The default JBoss startup scripts on Unix usually look something like:

```
nohup $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh $JBOSS_OPTS >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This is unfortunate because it's sends stderr to /dev/null.  Usually this is not a problem, because once log4j initializes, then most application output will go to boot.log or server.log.  However, for thread dumps, and other low level errors they get lost.

Your best bet is to change the startup script to redirect stdout and stderr to a file.  Additionally, one thing that's overlooked in the default setup is redirect stdin.  For daemon processes it's a best practice to redirect stdin to /dev/null.  For example:

```
nohup $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh $JBOSS_OPTS >> console-$(date +%Y%m%d).out 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

Lastly, if you have a running process, you can use `jstack`, which is included with the JRE, to get a thread dump.  This will output to the console from which it's invoked.  I prefer the output from `kill -3`, but `jstack` also allows you to view native stack frames.

Answer (score 1):

If this is on *nix, when you delete a file, everyone who has that file still open will continue to write to the old (now missing) file. The file will only be really deleted when all file handles to it are closed.

You would have to cause the JVM to close and re-open the log file. Not sure if this can be done without a restart.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into jmx and find jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService you can then invoke the reconfigure method which should cause log4j to reopen any of its log files.  Then the kill -quit should work.